# How can I remove an expression giving a word and start and end character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to remove an expression from a text giving a word and start and end character.
For example:

```
http://removecharacter.com?key=keyvalue&product=productid&user=userid
http://exampleremove.com?id=keyvalue&prodID=productid&login=userid
```

I want to remove `productid` for all my urls (parameter name is not the same for all urls, but the parameter value it is).

So I my urls will be:

```
http://removecharacter.com?key=keyvalue&user=userid
http://exampleremove.com?id=keyvalue&login=userid
```

The giving word is `productid` and the delimiter `&` and `&`.
I was playing with `CHARINDEX`, `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions but without any success

Comment: _I was playing with CHARINDEX LEFT and RIGHT function but any success_ --> Could you please show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(url NVARCHAR(1000))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('http://removecharacter.com?key=keyvalue&product=productid&user=userid'),
('http://exampleremove.com?id=keyvalue&prodID=productid&login=userid'),
('http://exampleremove.com?id=keyvalue&login=userid')


;WITH cte AS(SELECT *, 
                    REVERSE(url) AS newurl, 
                    CHARINDEX('&ditcudorp', REVERSE(url)) pt 
             FROM @t WHERE CHARINDEX('&ditcudorp', REVERSE(url)) > 0)
UPDATE cte SET url = REVERSE(STUFF(newurl, pt, CHARINDEX('&', newurl, pt + 1) - pt, ''))

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Output:

```
url
http://removecharacter.com?key=keyvalue&user=userid
http://exampleremove.com?id=keyvalue&login=userid
http://exampleremove.com?id=keyvalue&login=userid
```

In `cte` you are reversing `url` and find index of `'%&ditcudorp%'`. Then you are replacing all characters in position between index of `'%&ditcudorp%'` and index of next `'%&%'` with empty char.

Comment: Let me try with this! Tell u something

Comment: `CHARINDEX` will work as well instead of `PATINDEX`.

Comment: @ughai, yes that is logical to use same functions.